# Popup window without JavaScript?

Tags: html, href

I can use `window.open('the link here','name','height=x,width=x')` to make a popup window.  Is this possible without JavaScript at all, using the `href` tag or similar?

Something like `<a href="popup:http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow Popup</a>` where the `popup:` will cause the popup similarly to the way `mailto:` sends mail.

Comment: Why can't you use javascript?

Comment: @EthanBrouwer 1. Im just curious, and 2. it would make some work a bit easier since I wont have to go back and forth between HTML and JavaScript

Comment: You can use the target attribute. But then you will not have the features the JavaScript pop up has.

Comment: If you want to do web development, and you want the website to be functional, you're going to have to use javascript and css and html. It's really hard (I would even go so far as to say nearly impossible) to make a good website without all three.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer I know, but I'm just mainly curious if it is possible at all.

Comment: Can it be something like a modal `div` with an `iFrame` inside it or it has to be 100% new browser window?

Comment: It has to be a 100% new browser window.  I'm not sure if this is possible.  I'm pretty sure it is impossible but I know I'm not the smartest person with web coding, so I was trying to see if anyone knew of a way.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith oh yes.  I couldn't find any other related questions so i asked.  But i was wrong, there are at least 2 others.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `target` attribute to open in a new window

```
<a href="popup:http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stackoverflow Popup</a>
```

Some documentation is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: i tried the target="_blank" but it just opens in a new tab, not a new window.  I'm looking for a universal command, not one that does one thing on some browsers, and something else on other browsers.  This is the closest command I have found so far to a popup.

Comment: The answer the OP is looking for is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

The popup could be a modal window?

There´s a way using CSS, as taugh in SevenSignature[[1]](http://www.sevensignature.com/blog/code/pure-css-popup-without-javascript/).

Comment: I'm more looking for a new whole window, not just a modal window. Thanks though

Comment: worked for me...